# SQLPlus : default define settings

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, sqlplus

My workstation is `Ubuntu 14.04`. I have `Oracle Express 11g` installed. Whenever i run the define command in `SQLPlus`, is see the define _editor = "ed". Is there a way to change that permanently to `gedit` instead of defining my preferred editor with every new session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this.

Edit your shell dot file (`.profile`, `.bash_profile` etc) to add:

```
export EDITOR=gedit
```

Or, you can create the `sqlplus` equivalent of a Unix dot file. Create a file called `glogin.sql` and place it in `$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin`, then add this to it:

```
DEFINE _EDITOR=gedit
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using the either glogin.sql or login.sql. The former is run whenever anyone logs into SQL*Plus and the latter is specific to a user. Im not currently in a position to install it myself to try out but this link to the Oracle docs should help.
[Configuring SQL*Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch2.htm#sthref398)